# How does sanitize the sql parameter

Tags: c#

I write these code all are working fine but there is a warning coming that sanitize the sql parameter.

```
private DataSet ExcelToDataSet(string fileData)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(fileData);

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            // Get all Sheets in Excel File
            DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            // Loop through all Sheets to get data
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                    continue;

                // Get all rows from the Sheet
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = sheetName;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            }

            cmd = null;
            conn.Close();
        }

        return (ds);
    }
```

I have to sanitize the following  line

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
```

Comment: You can't and you don't need to. your sheet name does not come from using input, and you are not reading from a database.

Comment: @Peled  can you clear more through a example

Comment: This is one of the few exceptions where it's perfectly fine to concatenate strings to build your sql query. So you should suppress that warning.

Comment: Usually, when writing SQL Statements, you need to use parameters to pass the data from user input into the sql statement, to prevent SQL Injection attacks. That's why you get this warning. However, there is nothing you can do about it since it's impossible to parameterize identifiers in SQL, and you don't need to do it because you are not concatenating user input, and you are not running this query on a database, so even if you could use SQL injection, the worst you can do is corrupt a single file.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow table and column identifiers cannot be parametrized.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when writing SQL Statements, you need to use parameters to pass the data from user input into the sql statement, to prevent SQL Injection attacks. That's why you get this warning. However, there is nothing you can do about it since it's impossible to parameterize identifiers in SQL, and you don't need to do it because you are not concatenating user input, and you are not running this query on a database, so even if you could use SQL injection, the worst you can do is corrupt a single file

Comment: the polite thing to do when posting other people's comments is to mention that, even if you post them as community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I did not notice this was a `OleDbConnection`, the database you are connecting to may not have the same functionality to quote an identifier. I am leaving this answer here in case someone comes across this question and needs the same thing but for a SQL connection.

---

As the others have said, there is no need to worry about the warning in this case as the data is not coming from user data.

However everyone is wrong about the fact you cannot parameterize an identifier. You need to build the query dynamically server side and use the [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) function but it is possible.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
{
    string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
        continue;

    // Get all rows from the Sheet
    cmd.CommandText = @"
declare @sql nvarchar(114);
set @sql = N'select * from ' + quotename(@sheetname)
exec sp_executesql @sql
";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sheetname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = sheetName;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = sheetName;

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

This will generate a dynamic query that will safely escape the name of the table.

Comment: `sp_executesql` is a system procedure in SQL Server. I very much doubt you can run that on excel. Please note that the method name in the question is `ExcelToDataSet`.

Comment: Yes, I did read it. Still I think that this answer doesn't fit the question.